# Enable tab autocompletion for a parameter's value, while still accepting a different value

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I'd like to use a set of predefined values for a parameter, so that tab autocompletion will be possible, while I still could pass a different value to that parameter.

So far all the pages I've visited mention `ValidateSet`, `DynamicParam`, or casting a custom enum, but it doesn't address what I want. Let's say I have:

```
function test {
    Param(
        [ValidateSet("Paris", "London", "Madrid", "Berlin")]
        $city
    )
}
```

But what if I then wanted to run `test -city Rome`?

Is there a way to have both the convenience of tab completion (running through "Paris", "London", "Madrid", and "Berlin") and the flexibility of being allowed to pass another value?
Maybe catching the corresponding exception and in the catch block passing it to the parameter? If so, how could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a custom `ArgumentCompleter` instead of `ValidateSet`:

```
function test
    { Param (
    [ArgumentCompleter( {@( "Paris","London","Madrid","Berlin" ) -like $args[2] + '*'})]
    $city)
}
```

You can combine that with `ValidateScript` as well, not sure about `ValidateSet`.